# Wordpress Display Current page and parent/children

Tags: php, wordpress, nav

I'm trying to create a sidebar navigation that has the current page and it's children displayed (or if it's the child page, it's siblings and the parent page)

I can only get the children or, when on a child, siblings to display.

How can I get

- Parent
- Child
- Child

To display when on either the parent or child Pages? I don't want the parent page's siblings to display and nothing I try seems to work!

Thanks

```
            <?php
                        //GET CHILD PAGES IF THERE ARE ANY
                        $children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);

                        //GET PARENT PAGE IF THERE IS ONE
                        $parent = $post->post_parent;

                        //DO WE HAVE SIBLINGS?
                        $siblings =  get_pages('child_of='.$parent);

                        if( count($children) != 0) {
                           $args = array(
                             'depth' => 1,
                             'title_li' => '',
                             'child_of' => $post->ID
                           );

                        } elseif($parent != 0) {
                            $args = array(
                                 'depth' => 1,
                                 'title_li' => '',
                                 'child_of' => $parent
                               );
                        }
                        //Show pages if this page has more than one sibling 
                        // and if it has children 
                        if(count($siblings) > 1 && !is_null($args))   
                        {?>


                             <ul class="pages-list">
                             <?php wp_list_pages($args);  ?>
                             </ul>

    <?php } ?>
```